# Edge padding for scrollable tab row

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have a question regarding ScrollableTabRow and edge padding

is there a possibility to set padding only for the items inside, and not the left and right edge?

simplified code: https://gist.github.com/a/4cd4994c91b4de2c59d7f6a1f5f1da12

What i need is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4nkS.jpg

but i get something like this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhXtr.jpg

maybe i’m setting something wrong, or there is some internal padding that i cannot change? (Basically i need to set the padding between items to be 16.dp)

i managed to get something like i want using lazy row:
https://gist.github.com/a/4fdb1b124e067e5ec8d50b933477bea7

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxMYy.jpg

but that would mean implementing logic for the indicator, and if possible i’d like to avoid that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldnt find a solution, so i went with lazy row and custom indicator

Answer (score 4):

You can use `edgePadding = 0.dp` for remove this padding like this:

```
crollableTabRow(
        selectedTabIndex = 0, indicator = { tabPositions ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[pagerState.currentPage])
                    .height(4.dp)
                    .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                    .background(color = Color.Blue, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            ) {})
        }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), edgePadding = 0.dp, backgroundColor = colorResource(
            id = R.color.white
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just use in ScrollableTabRow

```
edgePadding = 0.dp,
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use
edgepadding = 0
to remove starting and ending padding of scrollable row tab in compose

Comment: Answer is duplicated

Answer (score -1):

I can't read your code.

I solve your problem:

> Basically i need to set the padding between items to be 16.dp

by adding a Tab warpper and set padding for it.

```
@Composable
fun Sample(){
    ScrollableTabRow(
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        selectedTabIndex = 0,
        edgePadding = 24.dp,
        modifier = Modifier.height(80.dp)
    ) {
        (1..20).forEach { index ->
            Tab(
                selected = false,
                onClick = { },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
            ){
                Text("DemoBox_$index")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]